# Pointer / Functions combination difficult to understand

Tags: function, pointers

What is the meaning of following statement.

```
((void*(*)(void*))keepfunc)(val)
```

Note:- In general I have problem understanding such expressions. Could, someone
Please suggest me some good material(web or book) for this?

Comment: It's from a 'C' library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try "parsing" the expression from inside out:

```
void*(*)(void*)
```

function pointer to a function expecting a pointer of void and returnning a pointer of void

```
(void*(*)(void*))keepfunc
```

cast to a function pointer expecting a pointer of void and returnning a pointer of void

```
((void*(*)(void*))keepfunc)(val)
```

This should be wrong, since a function pointer must be dereferenced before it can be called. It should look something like this:

```
(*(void*(*)(void*))keepfunc)(val)
```

Was this a working example from a textbook on C programming?

Comment: This is from MuPDF library, exact expression is as follows.item->val = ((void*(*)(void*))keepfunc)(val);

Answer (score 0):

This is a cast that casts keepfunc to a function pointer that accepts a void* parameter and returns a void* result value, and then evaluates the function by passing val as the parameter (although, i think there should be an asterisk before keepfunc, because you need to deference the function pointer before calling it). I think you should just look up function pointers in google, that should clear things up.