# difficult pointer to function

Tags: c++, function

I am reading book "Thinking in C++" Bruce Eckel. The Chapter 3 in page 164(Polish edition)is about pointer to function.

Examples from the book:

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10]
float (*(*fp2)(int,int,float))(int)
double (*(*(*fp3)())[10])()
int (*(*f4())[10])()
```

Can you tell me how I should interpret this and what is created by these examples because I do not understand the book solution?

Comment: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: Use `cdecl`. This isn't an interesting question.

Comment: I object strongly to the notion that you need to know this in order to "think in C++".

Comment: cdecl.org is cool, but English to C gibberish would be even cooler.

Comment: This is just worthless trivia knowledge that you will likely never ever use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer / Functions combination difficult to understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894700/pointer-functions-combination-difficult-to-understand)

Comment: @john It does do English to C gibberish. Try it out.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this tricky rule will help you to unwind such conundrums:
http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's take 4: `int (*(*f4())[10])()`

It reads `f4` evaluated (`f4()`) and then dereferenced (`(*f4())`) can be subscribed (`(*f4())[10]`) then dereferenced (`(*(*f4())[10])`) and evaluated to give an `int` (`int (*(*f4())[10])()`).

It is thus a function returning a pointer of arrays to pointers of functions returning `int`.